# What is the difference between using conda pip install and conda skeleton?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I need to install a python package from pypi

Which are the differences between installing it directly in the conda enviroment using conda pip install,  and using conda skeleton to build a conda package from the pypi package, and then add install it to the conda enviroment.

Comment: Good question. Even I want to know .

Answer (score 0):

The difference is similar to using Software installer to install packages and `apt-get install` to install packages in Ubuntu. `conda pip` transfers whole control to `pip` for installing the required package whereas, `conda skeleton` uses functionality of conda itself to do all the necessary work step by step.